# Как найти дубликаты строк, в колонках которых содержатся значения null?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Исходная таблица:

[image: Исходная таблица]

Дублями считаются случаи:

[image: Дубли]

Т. е дублями в исходной таблице являются строки
3-4, 5-6, 7-8, 9-10, 11-12.

Строки 1-2 в исходной таблице - не дубли.

Нужно получить все строки, кроме первых двух.
Нужный результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Структура таблицы:

```
create table transport (   
  id serial,
  enginenumber varchar(10),
  carcassnumber varchar(10)
);

insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values('A', 'B');
insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values('A', 'C');

insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values('A', 'B');
insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values('A', 'B');

insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values('A', 'B');
insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values('A', null);

insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values('A', 'B');
insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values(null, 'B');

insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values('A', null);
insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values('A', null);

insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values(null, 'B');
insert into transport(enginenumber, carcassnumber) values(null, 'B');
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9gQNjVwLn3W11pnCcr8NEs/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача выглядит странной, т.к. обычно в табличных данных нет привязки к следованию строк. Для простого запроса строки 1 и 3 будут одинаковые.

Если использовать аналитические функции, то в них можно обращаться к значением предыдущих/следующих строк.

```sql
select
  rn, enginenumber, carcassnumber
from (
  select
    row_number() over w rn,
    enginenumber, carcassnumber,
    lag(enginenumber) over w lag_enginenumber, -- предыдущее значение
    lag(carcassnumber) over w lag_carcassnumber,
    lead(enginenumber) over w lead_enginenumber, -- следующее значение
    lead(carcassnumber) over w lead_carcassnumber
  from transport
  window w as (order by id)) t
where (mod(t.rn, 2) = 1 and coalesce(t.enginenumber, t.lead_enginenumber, '') = coalesce(t.lead_enginenumber, t.enginenumber, '')
and coalesce(t.carcassnumber, t.lead_carcassnumber, '') = coalesce(t.lead_carcassnumber, t.carcassnumber, ''))
or
(mod(t.rn, 2) = 0 and coalesce(t.enginenumber, t.lag_enginenumber, '') = coalesce(t.lag_enginenumber, t.enginenumber, '')
and coalesce(t.carcassnumber, t.lag_carcassnumber, '') = coalesce(t.lag_carcassnumber, t.carcassnumber, ''));
```

Если строки следуют в порядке возрастания идентификаторов, то следующую/предыдущую строку можно искать через подзапрос и сравнение с минимальным/максимальным идентификатором относительно текущего.